# Calling map on an Option<Rc<Struct>> works differently than calling it on a Option<Rc<i32>>

Tags: rust, smart-pointers, dereference, reference-counting

I'm new to Rust and I'm trying to figure out why `Rc` is behaving differently when being passed to a closure. My full code is the following:

```
use std::rc::Rc;

struct Something {
    value: i32
}

fn main() {
    let wrapped_struct = Some(Rc::new(Something { value: 1 }));
    let wrapped_integer = Some(Rc::new(1));
    // Case 1: This works
    let works: Option<i32> = wrapped_struct.map(|i| { i.value });
    // Case 2: This fails
    let fails: Option<i32> = wrapped_integer.map(|i| { i });
}
```

The error message is:

```
   |
13 |     let fails: Option<i32> = wrapped_integer.map(|i| { i });
   |                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected i32, found struct `std::rc::Rc`
   |
   = note: expected type `std::option::Option<i32>`
              found type `std::option::Option<std::rc::Rc<{integer}>>`
```

What I don't understand is why in the first closure (Case 1) I can use `i` as a `Something` (I'd expect `Rc<Something>`) but in the second one (Case 2) I can't use `i` as an `i32` (I actually get an `Rc<i32>`).

I appreciate any pointers to the relevant documentation. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type of the `i` in both closures is actually `Rc<Something>` and `Rc<i32>` respectively. `Rc` can be dereferenced to access its inner data, but there are places in Rust where dereferencing happens automatically, for convenience.

In the struct case, when you write `i.value`, it will automatically dereference `i` to access the field. It then returns a copy of the `i32`, because `i32` is a `Copy` type. So the type of the expression `i.value` is `i32`. It's as if you wrote `(*i).value`, but Rust did the dereferencing for you.

In the `i32` case, you are just returning the `i`, which still has type `Rc<i32>`. You can fix it by explicitly dereferencing:

```
wrapped_integer.map(|i| { *i });
```

---

See also:

- [What are Rust's exact auto-dereferencing rules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28519997/what-are-rusts-exact-auto-dereferencing-rules)

Comment: Ohh I see, didn't know about Rust's auto-dereferencing. Thank you for the linked post!